# Find absolute path of a file in python when knowing the last part of the path and the base directory?

Tags: python, filepath, glob, absolute-path, pathlib

Using python, I have the last parts of paths to existing files, like that:

```
sub_folder1/file1.txt
sub_folder2/file120.txt
sub_folder78/file99.txt
```

Note, that these paths are not the relative paths to the current folder I am working in, e.g., this `pandas.read_csv('sub_folder1/file1.txt')` would through a non-existing-file error. Nevertheless, I know all the files have the same base directory `base_dir`, but I don't know the absolute path. This means a file could be located like this:

```
base_dir/inter_folder1/sub_folder1/file1.txt
```

Or like this:

```
base_dir/inter_folder7/inter_folder4/.../sub_folder1/file1.txt
```

**Is there a function that returns the absolute path, when given the last part of the path and the base directory of a file (or equivalently, finding the intermediate folders)?** Should be looking like that:

```
absolut_path = some_func(end_path='bla/bla.txt', base_dir='BLAH')
```

I thought `pathlib` might have a solution, but couldn't find anything there. Thanks

---

I need this to do something like the below:

```
for end_path in list_of_paths:
    full_path = some_func(end_path=end_path, base_dir='base_dir')
    image = cv2.imread(full_path)
```

Comment: You will have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly easy to implement from `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def find(end_path: str, base_dir: str):
    for file in Path(base_dir).rglob("*"):
        if str(file).endswith(end_path):
            yield file
```

This is a [`generator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), to match the `pathlib` interface; as such it will yield `pathlib.PosixPath` objects. It will also find all matching files, for example:

```py
[str(f) for f in find(end_path="a.txt", base_dir="my_dir")]
# creates:
# ['my_dir/a.txt', 'my_dir/sub_dir/a.txt']
```

If you just want the first value you can just return the first item:

```py
def find_first(end_path: str, base_dir: str):
    for file in Path(base_dir).rglob("*"):
        if str(file).endswith(end_path):
            return str(file)

abs_path = find_first(end_path="a.txt", base_dir="my_dir")
```

---

A better function that would improve the lookup:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def find(pattern, suffixes, base_dir):
    for file in Path(base_dir).rglob(pattern):
        if any(str(file).endswith(suffix) for suffix in suffixes):
            yield str(file)

base_dir = "base_directory"
suffixes = [
    'sub_folder1/file1.txt', 
    'sub_folder2/file120.txt', 
    'sub_folder78/file99.txt',
]

for full_path in find(pattern="*.txt", suffixes=suffix, base_dir=base_dir):
    image = cv2.imread(full_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! The `yield` seems to be a problem later though, because my files are actually jpg and after I do `abs_path=find(end_path="a.jpg", base_dir="my_dir")` I try to apply `cv2.imread(str(abs_path))` and this results in the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mean'". Do you know how to make opencv read the path yielded in this way?

Comment: So this is a generator it can be thought of a iterable of _all_ the matching files, and it assumes there might be multiple matches. I've updated the answer to show how you can get a single value back; or you could send all matching files.

Comment: Thanks! Though, I get the error `name 'List' is not defined`. Furthermore, I think this computation would take very long for a lot of files (I need to do it on ca. 100 000). I am working now on computing `Path(base_dir).rglob(pattern)` only once, instead of for each file. And also trying to avoid all the loops, again for the sake of saving time.

Comment: That was my type hints, I've removed them. The updated function only uses `rglob` once but has to check each file that it finds to see whether it's in your list of targets (`suffixes`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for the sub-folder within the base folder e.g,

```py
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(base_dir)):
    if dirpath.endswith(subfolder1):
        print(dirpath)
```

You might want to also make sure that the file exists in that folder using:

```py
if dirpath.endswith("subfolder1") and "file1.txt" in files:
    print(dirpath)
```